# Relation between buffers and glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm trying to understand the relations between [`glGenBuffers`, `glBindData`, `glBufferData`, `glBufferSubData`] and `glVertexAttribPointer`.

I saw that you don't really have to use the buffers method (at least not in Android) but rather call `glVertexAttribPointer` directly, passing a pointer to the buffer object as the last parameter. (the buffers being a `FloatBuffer` in this case)

e.g.

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, vertexBuffer);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 16, colorBuffer);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, normalsBuffer);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, textureBuffer);
```

1) Why would I want to use the buffer methods? Only if my data is happened to be stacked together in one array?

2) How do openGL handle these direct (non buffer) functions behind the scenes? I saw that it calls `glVertexAttribPointerBounds` - does it actually stack it together to a single array of bytes?

3) If I do bind an array to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` - it means I have to use the stacked array version, and I won't be able to pass anymore direct objects, correct? i.e. I cannot do this:

```
int[] bufferVertices = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, bufferVertices, 0);
vertexBufferId = bufferVertices[0];
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferId);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeCoords.length * 4 , vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride,0);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 16, colorBuffer);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,12, normalsBuffer);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,8, textureBuffer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple buffer objects. If a vertex array buffer is bound, when [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called then the last parameter of  `glVertexAttribPointer` is treated as an offset to this buffer, but if no vertex buffer object is bound, then the last parameter is treated as a pointer to the data:

See [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification; 2.8. VERTEX ARRAYS; 21](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf):

> ```
> void VertexAttribPointer( uint index, int size, enum type, 
>                           boolean normalized,  sizei stride, 
>                           const void *pointer );
> ```
>
> ...
>   For each command, *pointer* specifies the location in memory of the first value of the first element of the array being specified.

See [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification; 2.9. BUFFER OBJECTS; 25](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf):

> ... When an array is sourced from
>   a buffer object, the *pointer* value of that array is used to compute an offset, in basic machine units, into the data store of the buffer object. ...

This means it is possible to do:

```
int[] bufferVertices = new int[4];
GLES20.glGenBuffers(4, bufferVertices, 0);

vertexBufferId = bufferVertices[0];
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferId);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeCoords.length * 4, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

colorBufferId = bufferVertices[1];
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferId);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeCoords.length * 4, colorBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

normlBufferId = bufferVertices[2];
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normlBufferId);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeCoords.length * 4, normalsBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

textureBufferId = bufferVertices[3];
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBufferId);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeCoords.length * 4, textureBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferId);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferId);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normlBufferId);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBufferId);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Comment: ok, nice! I think you forgot to increase the indices of the buffers. Do you also know how its treated behind the scenes? If I call glVertexAttribPointer with a pointer to a buffer (like I show in my question), does it first call (behind the scenes) BindBuffer on that buffer?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli That is not clearly specified. But in this case OpenGL doesn't know anything about the buffer size. The vertex array data is loaded to the GPU immediately at the draw call.

Answer (score 0):

1) The preferred way is to use buffer objects whenever possible. This ensures allocation of necessary GPU resources in advance. However, for dynamic geometry it is sometimes more convenient to call bufferless methods. In my experience, some drivers have shown better perfomance with bufferless methods even compared to using a buffer with GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW. But for static geometry the best approach is to use a GL buffer. This way the driver can avoid having to copy the vertex data before each draw call.

2) The common knowledge here is that when you pass a CPU side array to glVertexAttribPointer, it has to be copied by the driver during the subsequent glDraw* call. You can then modify the array and it will be copied during the next glDraw* call again. As for the layout of the vertex data in memory, I would bet that it is left as it is, since AFAIK GPUs can handle non-interleaved streams natively. Thus re-arranging them before a GL draw call would require a meaningless gather operation.

3) The mix of GL buffer and CPU array streams should work OK. This is a common scenario, where one part of the vertex data is static (e.g. texcoords), and another is dynamic (e.g. positions), the latter being transformed by CPU, for example.